# Sending values to C# wrapped C++ dll cause Unity crash

Tags: c++, dll, mono, swig, unity-game-engine

I have a C++ class I want to use in Unity(C#), so  I compiled a C++ dll and create a C# wrapper dll for it. I did this using SWIG.

When I do this:

```
Graph g = new Graph();
int k = g.AddNode();
```

It's fine, and I tried Debug.Log(k) to check the returned k value and it seems working right. So I think **I can call functions and get returning values**.

But when I try to do this, Unity will crash:

```
g.AddNode(num_of_nodes);
```

Seems **it will crash whenever I try to send values**. No idea why this is happening.

---

The class I want to wrap is [MaxFlow library of Yuri Boykov and Vladimir Kolmogorov](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/V.Kolmogorov/software.html). Anyone have any idea about how to use this library in Unity please help.

---

Original C++ add_node() function:

```
int Graph::add_node(int num)
{
    //assert(num > 0);

    if (node_last + num > node_max) reallocate_nodes(num);

    if (num == 1)
    {
        node_last -> first = NULL;
        node_last -> tr_cap = 0;
        node_last -> is_marked = 0;
        node_last -> is_in_changed_list = 0;

        node_last ++;
        return node_num ++;
    }
    else
    {
        memset(node_last, 0, num*sizeof(node));

        int i = node_num;
        node_num += num;
        node_last += num;
        return i;
    }
}
```

SWIG generated *_wrap.cxx, functions of AddNode:

```
//with send param (g.AddNode(num_of_nodes)), this one will crash
SWIGEXPORT int SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_Graph_add_node__SWIG_0(void * jarg1, int jarg2) {
  int jresult ;
  MaxFlowGraph::Graph *arg1 = (MaxFlowGraph::Graph *) 0 ;
  int arg2 ;
  MaxFlowGraph::Graph::int result;

  arg1 = (MaxFlowGraph::Graph *)jarg1; 
  arg2 = (int)jarg2; 
  result = (arg1)->add_node(arg2);
  jresult = result; 
  return jresult;
}

//without send param (g.AddNode()), this one works
SWIGEXPORT int SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_Graph_add_node__SWIG_1(void * jarg1) {
  int jresult ;
  MaxFlowGraph::Graph *arg1 = (MaxFlowGraph::Graph *) 0 ;
  MaxFlowGraph::Graph::int result;

  arg1 = (MaxFlowGraph::Graph *)jarg1; 
  result = (arg1)->add_node();
  jresult = result; 
  return jresult;
}
```

SWIG grnerated cs file, function of AddNode:

```
public int AddNode(int num)
{
    int ret = MaxFlowGraphPINVOKE.Graph_add_node__SWIG_0(swigCPtr, num);
    return ret;
}

public int AddNode()
{
    int ret = MaxFlowGraphPINVOKE.Graph_add_node__SWIG_1(swigCPtr);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but the best I can come up with based on the question.

I would start with a simpler example and work up from there.  For example, start by modifying your function to do nothing but return, like this:

```
int Graph::add_node(int num)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Does even that crash?  If so, then the problem isn't in the function and is likely in the wrapper code.  Maybe modify the wrapper code to also do nothing:

```
SWIGEXPORT int SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_Graph_add_node__SWIG_0(void * jarg1, int jarg2) {
   return 1;
}
```

Does that still crash?  If so, likely a deceleration issue or incorrect compiler settings (mixing of calling conventions, 32bit vs 64bit, incompatible libraries or external dependencies, etc).

If the first one above fixes the crash, then likely a bug in your code, mostly like I'd suspect the memset() -- I'd start adding more and more code back to the function until it crashes again, to figure out exactly where the crash is happening.

This is all assuming you aren't able to step through with a debugger -- I'll assume that if you could do that, you wouldn't be asking this question in the first place.  I'll try to help more if you provide more details, like the results to the above tests.

Edit: If it does get to your C++ code before crashing, you could try debugging using [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).